# Docusign API receiving status of optional sign here tab

Tags: php, api, docusignapi

I am using Docusign API (PHP) to request a signature by email using a PDF File. Inside the PDF are 2 sign_tabs/anchors and one is optional. I need information after completion if the optional sign_tab was signed. How do I get this information? Wether the  EnvelopeFormData::get or the envelope info via  Envelopes::get provide any info about the sign_tabs itself...

Here is how I implemented the tabs:

```
$sign_here = new SignHere(['anchor_string' => '/sign_here/',]);

$sign_here_optional = new SignHere(
['anchor_string' =>'/sign_here_direct_debit_mandate/',
'optional'      => TRUE,]);
```

Thank you.

Björn

Answer (score 0):

The better way to get this information is using the [DocuSign Connect webhook](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/). This way you don't have to poll DocuSign to know when the envelope was signed.

Regardless, [the API call](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/) to retrieve an envelope has an option to get all tab data.

You would have to specify `'include' => 'tabs'` in your options object to get the tabs back for a specific envelope.

Comment: I do not get any specific information about the signHere Tabs, only from Text Tabs (via recipientFormData Array Response). If I use 2 signHere Tabs and one is optional, there is no info about their specific status, only a global information about the envelope itself (completed).

Comment: Did you call the API endpoint I had in the answer and specified 'tabs' to be included?